# Integrity of foreign keys on a table where first FK is a PK on one table but not one the second

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   some_data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table2
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   table1_id INT NOT NULL,
   some_data VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT fk_table2_table1 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(id)
)

CREATE TABLE table3
(
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   table1_id INT NOT NULL,
   table2_id INT NOT NULL,
   some_data VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT fk_table3_table2 FOREIGN KEY (table2_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
   CONSTRAINT fk_table3_table1 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(id)
)
```

While the fk constraints on table3 maintains the integrity of presence/validation of the table1_id and table2_id values, I'm looking for a way to also check for the integrity of table1_id to be the table1_id in table2 where table2(id) is table2_id.
Is there a way to check for this constraint in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relational databases the foreign keys are not checked transitively. The only way of ensuring the FKs are *well connected* as you want to, is to use composite keys. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   some_data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
   table1_id INT NOT NULL,
   id INT NOT NULL,
   some_data VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (table1, id), -- composite PK
   CONSTRAINT fk_table2_table1 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id) REFERENCES table1(id)
)

CREATE TABLE table3 (
   table1_id INT NOT NULL,
   table2_id INT NOT NULL,
   id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   some_data VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (table1_id, table2_id, id), -- optional composite PK
   CONSTRAINT fk_table3_table2 FOREIGN KEY (table1_id, table2_id) 
     REFERENCES table2 (table1_id, id) -- references table_2 composite PK
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The three tables are not normalized enough and would actually lead to duplication of data. You do not need to reference table1_id in table3 since it is already referenced in table2. A table2 record already references table1_id. You just need to remove table1_id in table3 plus the Constraint fk_table3_table1 and all will be well.